# How is scalaz able to do "A \/ B", and how can I do my own "B.??" or "A <??> B"

Tags: scala, implicit, scalaz

I am relatively new to scala implicits, but if I wanted to be able to do `5.??`, I would do:

```scala
class MyInt(int: Int) {
  // Useless, just to make a point
  def ?? : Int = int * 100
}

implicit def toMyInt(int: Int): MyInt =
  MyInt(int)
```

My question is: How is scalaz able to do `A \/ B`, and how could I do the same thing as above, adding my own operators (but to work with types)?
A little bit of context about what Im trying to play around and do:

```scala
abstract class Err(val message: String) { /* ... */ }

sealed trait MaybeErr[+E <: Err, +T] { /* ... */ }
```

The closest I have been able to get:

```scala
type ??[+T] = MaybeErr[Err, T]

type <??>[+E <: Err, +T] = MaybeErr[E, T]

def div1(t: Int, b: Int): ??[Int] = /* ... */

def div2(t: Int, b: Int): <??>[OtherErr, Int] = /* ... */
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
// T.?? = MaybeErr[Err, T]

// E <??> T = MaybeErr[E, T]

def div1(t: Int, b: Int): Int.?? = /* ... */

def div2(t: Int, b: Int): OtherErr <??> Int = /* ... */
```

Comment: `\/` is a type name. `A \/ B` is a syntax sugar of `\/[A, B]`

Comment: How do I get my own syntatic sugar then?

Comment: It works out of the box. It doesn't work for your case because the class name cannot start with `?` or `<`

Comment: Cool, thanks. I got `A |??| B` working, but it seems like `A.??`, or any variant of that is not going to work?

Comment: No postfix doesn't work for class parameter. It's also discouraged for method invocation too now.

Answer (score 1):

> How is scalaz able to do `A \/ B`, and how could I do the same thing as above

Any binary type constructor `C[A, B]` can alternatively be written in infix form `A C B` (or `C:[A, B]` as `B C: A` for type constructors ending in a `:` colon), see [section 3.10 *Infix Types*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#infix-types) of the [Scala 2.13 Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#infix-types).

You can see the definition of `\/` in [`core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Either.scala#L27):

> ```scala
> sealed abstract class \/[A, B] extends Product with Serializable
> ```